# Arquillian test works only if it is placed in root package

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

I have a simple Wildfly Swarm application which has JAX-RS endpoint and Service class injected into the endpoint through CDI.

I wrote an integration test for my app which looks somehow like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@DefaultDeployment(type = WAR)
public class MyEndpointIT {

    @ArquillianResource
    private URI uri;

    @Deployment
    public static WARArchive createDeployment() throws Exception {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WARArchive.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGet() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Invocation.Builder request = client.target(uri)
                .path("/api/my-endpoint")
                .request();

        Response response = request.get();

        assertThat(response.getStatusInfo(), is(OK));
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The test works only if I put it into the root level of package hierarchy.
Let's say my project structure looks like this.

```
com
├ mycompany
| ├ rest
| | └ MyEndpoint.java
| ├ service
| | └ MyService.java
```

If I create the integration test in `com.mycompany.rest` it fails with `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mycompany/service/MyService;
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.service.MyService from [Module "deployment.MyEndpointIT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

But if I add my test one level higher it works fine (mens into the `com.mycompany` package).

**Question:** Why the test work in such a strange way? Is it documented behaviour? How can I put my tests into the same packages where the tested classes are?

I also tried to use trick like this:

```
warArchive.addClass(MyService.class);
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

One: if you add a `@DefaultDeployment` annotation, you shouldn't add a `@Deployment` annotation at the same time. `@DefaultDeployment` builds a deployment archive for you based on some "sensible defaults".

Two, the "sensible defaults" don't work for you at the current form. `@DefaultDeployment` builds a deployment archive that contains classes from the package the test resides in and all the subpackages. If that doesn't work for you, you can always remove the `@DefaultDeployment` annotation and build a deployment manually using plain old `@Deployment`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with `@DefaultDeployment`. I added it because IntelliJ highlighted the `@RunWith` part asking for adding the method. The test works without it. But it fails with the same error if I move it to the correct package. I also tried removing `@DefaultDeployment` and leaving the `@Deployment` method - this way the test doesn't pass the assert - the received code is 404 (independently from the package I use). I tried manually adding the service  via `warArchive.addClass` but from the debug I found that it gets intialized with mock. Any idea what I need to do to init the service?

Answer (score 0):

when you create your WARArchive, please try to add your desired packages:

```
return ShrinkWrap.create(WARArchive.class, "your-company.war")
         .addPackages(true, "com.yourcompany");
```

Comment: I tried this earlier - doesn't work independently from the package